# Preventing memory freeing in STL Container

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

I have an STL container (std::list) that I am constantly reusing. By this I mean I

1. push a number of elements into the container
2. remove the elements during processing
3. clear the container
4. rinse and repeat a large number of times

When profiling using callgrind I am seeing a large number of calls to `new` (`malloc`) and `delete` (`free`) which can be quite expensive. I am therefore looking for some way to preferably preallocate a reasonably large number of elements. I would also like my allocation pool to continue to increase until a high water mark is reach and for the allocation pool to continue to hang onto the memory until the container itself is deleted.

Unfortunately the standard allocator continually resizes the memory pool so I am looking for some allocator that will do the above without me having to write my own.

Does such an allocator exist and where can I find such an allocator?

I am working on both Linux using GCC and Android using the STLPort.

**Edit**: Placement `new` is ok, what I want to minimize is heap walking which is expensive. I would also like all my object to be as close to eachother as possible to minimize cache misses.

Comment: new and delete's may be the object destructors and constructors contained in the container which makes it somewhow unavoidable

Comment: @fatih_k This would only hold if the list holds pointers to dynamically allocated objects, though. Which the OP would probably know to avoid, I believe.

Comment: @Angew, destructors of objects are only called when contained elements are objects instead of being pointers. std::container's does not take the ownership of pointers

Comment: placement new is ok, I just want to minimize calls to malloc and free

Comment: I think you should have a look at these allocator examples:

- http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/improving-performance-with-custom-pool-a/184406243
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

Comment: @fatih_k The OP was complaining about `new` and `delete`. These are operators for dynamic allocation - they are not called at all when objects are not dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Angew, If you are storing pointers in the vector or list it will not delete the objects' memory, giving you a memory leak

Comment: @fatih_k If they are raw pointers. Anyway, my point was that `new` and `delete` cannot be the objects' ctors/dtors.

Comment: Hmmm... How do you plan on reinitializing elements? I am not a top expert but I think the memory operations can only come from `ctors` and `dtors` of the elements held on list AND the list nodes. You can avoid reconstructing list nodes by switching to `std::vector`. `vector` should also give better cache coherency and lower ovehead perhaps. Aside of this, you will always have to deallocate object if you delete it. Alternatively you could reiterate over objects existing in vector and reinitialize them. But this would be beneficial only if allocations within your objets are costly.

Comment: @Angew I'd expect that - for each `push_back` - internally, `std::list<T>` will `malloc()` a block big enough to hold a `T`, and it's own housekeeping, and then copy contruct - via placement new a copy of the passed item.

Comment: I forgot to all that my containers either contain pointers or some other Plain Old Datatype (POD)

Comment: What about not using a `std::list` at all, but a `std::vector`. I hope you're using the `std::list` because of its guaranties regarding iterator invalidation and *not* because of its supposedly faster insertions and removals, because that is a half-truth (as you've just seen yourself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The allocator [`boost::fast_pool_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html) is designed for use with `std::list`.

The documentation claims that "If you are seriously concerned about performance, use `boost::fast_pool_allocator` when dealing with containers such as `std::list`, and use `boost::pool_allocator` when dealing with containers such as `std::vector`."

Note that `boost::fast_pool_allocator` is a singleton and by default it never frees allocated memory. However, it is implemented using [`boost::singleton_pool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/singleton_pool.html) and you can make it free memory by calling the static functions `boost::singleton_pool::release_memory()` and `boost::singleton_pool::purge_memory()`.

Comment: this is is the approach I am interested in. I will take a look at this in more detail

Comment: I like the idea. My only problem is that the pool is a singleton and the memory is never freed which is a problem when using a long running program for which my list is seldom used.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, now!

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by adding "next" pointers to my already existing data structures and managing the linked list myself. However for a general case, I like this answer best.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you may be just using the wrong kind of container: With a list, each element occupies a separate chunk of memory, to allow individual inserts/deletes - so every addition/deletion form the list will require a separate `new()/delete()`.

If you can use a `std::vector` instead, then you can `reserve` the required size before adding the items.

Also for deletion, it's usually best not to remove the items individually. Just call `clear()` on the container to empty. it.

---

**Edit:** You've now made it clear in the comments that your '*remove the elements during processing*' step is removing elements from the middle of the list and must not invalidate iterators, so switching to a vector is not suitable. I'll leave this answer for now (for the sake of the comment thread!)

Comment: Except I would like to remove elements in the middle of the list without the memory shuffle that std::vector will entail

Comment: @doron Does the order inside the contain matter? If not, you could simply swap to-be-deleted with the last element and `pop_back()`. No shuffle.

Comment: @doron Still, the memory shuffle might be quite less than you think. Look at Bjarne Stroustrup explaining the benefits of vector vs list http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style (starts at 44:40) In short, even if you remove a lot and insert a lot, the time for linear search in a list completely dominates the processing time, because the objects are scattered around in memory and that hurts cpu caching.

Comment: @doron *"Except I would like to remove elements in the middle of the list without the memory shuffle that std::vector will entail"* - You're already using a profiler, so just risk a test and compare the speed of vector's shuffle madness to list's allocation madness. The results might be surprising (and might shatter your believes on big-O notation ;)).

Comment: @Felix. I am aware of this but if my allocator makes a grab for a large number of node elements up front and only allocates internally off a free list, we should get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @doron No, have you watched the video? Stroustrup specifically mentions allocation as not being the cause of the bad performance of lists.

Comment: @Christian - replacing list with vector does not work since I need the stronger iterator guarantees offered by std::list. vector::erase, invalidates iterators, list::erase does not.

Comment: @doron Then this is indeed a perfect (if not the only reasonable) use-case for a `std::list` and is what you should have mentioned in your first comment on this answer instead of the perfomance argument, since the former is a hard reason why you cannot use a `std::vector` and not a to be discussed away pseudo-reason.

Comment: @Roddy, please keep the answer up. I like to ask questions that are of slightly wider interest than just me, this answer might not be applicable to me but other people might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and benchmark your app with http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html, I've seen some good improvements in some of my projects (no numbers at hand though, sorry)

**EDIT**: Seems the code/download has been moved there: http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1

Comment: I am trying to avoid malloc entirely since malloc allows memory allocations of all sizes. In my container, I do a memory grab and then use the fact that all the elements are the same size so that there is no need for heap walking.

Comment: Read through their tests and benchmarks, they are very good with small objects, and tcmalloc never reduces the heap (malloc always grows when needed, free never relinquish to the OS)

Answer (score -1):

Comment was too short so I will post my thoughts as an answer.

IMO, new/delete can come only from two places in this context.

I believe `std::list<T>` is implemented with some kind of nodes as normally lists are, for various reasons. Therefore, each insertion and removal of an element will have to result in new/delete of a node. Moreover, if the object of type `T` has any allocations and deallocations in c'tor/d'tor, they will be called as well.

You can avoid recreation of standard stuff by reiterating over existing nodes instead of deleting them. You can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you want to squeeze it to c-level.

Nonetheless, for every object created there must be called a destructor. The only way I see to avoid creations and destructions is to use `T::operator=` when reiterating over container, or maybe some c++13 `move` stuff if its suitable in your case.

Comment: Well, constructors and destructors won't neccessarily cause a `new/delete` anyway and I guess restructuring the to be contained elements is not an option for the OP at all.

Comment: @ChristianRau, that is why I said "if the object of type T has any allocations and deallocations". Well actually I made a typo.  I rephrased it. Of course they do not have new/delete, but if they have, they will surely manifest.